# jquery alternatives to .load

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to grab a file and load it into a div on a click command. I know that I can do this with load but....

I want to be able to regenerate the same content as many times without clearing the last instance of it. Can anyone recommend another jQuery call to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.getMoreContent = function()
{
    var collection = this;

    $.ajax( {
        url: 'page.html',
        success: function( data )
        {
            collection.append( data );
        }
    } );

    return collection;
};

$( '#someDiv' ).getMoreContent();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/dyRjQ/2/

Or:

```
$( '#someDiv' ).append(
    $( '<div>' ).load( 'page.html' )
);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/dyRjQ/3/

Comment: Thankls alot, this seems like a great solution. 
1 Question:

How can I replace inline HTML with an PHP file?
'data: {
            html: '<p>More content</p>',
            delay: 1
        },'

Comment: That live JSfiddle example is using JSFiddle's "echo API" to mimick AJAX. It requires that I post to their URL, sending the data which I want sent back. You simply need to use what I pasted here on StackFlow and replace 'page.html' with your own URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the content into a new element each time:

```
$('<div>').load('...').appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to display external files on web page, is to embed it. You can do something like that:

```
$("#target embed").attr("src","filename.pdf");
```

Your HTML should be similar to that:

```
<div id="target">
   <embed src="" width="500" height="375">
</div>
```